# Как на typescript заполнить массив объектов класса данными с локального json

Tags: typescript

```
class Task {
    question: string;
    ansver: string;
}
```

Json

```
[{"question": "...", "answer": "..."},{"question": "...", "answer": "..."},{"question": "...", "answer": "."}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = require('data.json');

interface TaskData {
    question: string;
    answer: string;
}

class Task implements TaskData {
    question: string;
    answer: string;

    constructor(data: TaskData) {
       this.question = data.question;
       this.answer = data.answer;
    }
}

function isTaskData(arg: any): arg is TaskData {
    return arg && !!arg.question && !!arg.answer;
}

const tasks: Task[] = [];

for (const record of data) {
   if (!isTaskData(record)) { continue; }
   tasks.push(new Task(record));
}
```